# Example of non-isomorphic sheaves with same stalks and unique non-trivial map

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Consider a smooth projective variety $X$ over an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero, can we have two non-isomorphic coherent sheaves $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$ such that $\mathcal{F}_x\cong\mathcal{G}_x$ and there exists a unique non-trivial morphism $\mathcal{F}\rightarrow\mathcal{G}$ (up to a constant) of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules?

Can such example live in $\mathbb{P}^n$ or high dimensional hypersurfaces?

Comment: You can always multiply your morphism by a scalar, so you mean "unique up to a scalar". The answer is no: take $\mathcal{F}=\mathcal{O}_X$ and $\mathcal{G}=L$, a line bundle with $h^0(L)=1$.

Comment: @abx I'm not sure how this answers the question - to give a "no" answer you would need to show that there is no such pair $\mathcal{F,G}$.

Comment: @Wojowu: Oops, right: this gives a **yes** answer.

Comment: Could anyone please name a concrete example? I think there are no such line bundles in projective space or high dimensional hypersurfaces (which has picard number one).